# regex for pattern validation using html in coldfusion

Tags: regex, validation, coldfusion

I have a variable "CustCd" that is 7 digits long. The first digit can be either a number or letter but the last 6 digits (positions 2-7) have to be numeric. I am trying to use a regex where pattern = "[0-9 A-Z a-z]{1} [0-9]{2,7}" with class validate required and it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="CustCd" id="CustCd" 
    size="7" maxlength="7" 
    pattern="[0-9 A-Z a-z]{1} [0-9]{2,7}" 
    title="Customer Code" class="validate required" />
```

This is my first time using regexes so I think I may be overlooking something. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you expect an HTML input field to validate itself?

Comment: If you are using HTML5 validation, then the question really has nothing to do with CF.  Tip: Descriptions like "not working" are very ambiguous. Instead, please give a brief description of the *actual* result - and how it differs from what you *expected*.

Comment: *RE: This is my first time using regexes* Though extra white space improves readability for humans, regex engines are not human ;-) So including extra spaces actually changes what the expression matches. So `[0-9(space)A-Z(space)a-z]` will match a-z, A-Z, 0-9 *OR* a space character.

Comment: "If you are using HTML5 validation" - @sjstroot are you 100% positive that every user of your system is using an HTML 5 capable browser? If not, then that pattern attribute will do nothing for you. Also, make sure you're running the same validation on that data on the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$` as your pattern. Remember this validation is done against the JavaScript regEx engine.

```
<input type="text" name="CustCd" id="CustCd" size="7" maxlength="7" 
  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$"  title="Customer Code" class="validate required" />
```

Also make sure you have the correct doctype on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Explanation via [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1} match a single character present in the list below
  Quantifier: {1} Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)
  a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
  A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
[0-9]{6} match a single character present in the list below
  Quantifier: {6} Exactly 6 times
  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Full sample code to try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="CustCd" id="CustCd" size="7" maxlength="7" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[0-9]{6}" title="Customer Code" class="validate required" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The doc you referred above also mentions this: *The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset.* so you may need something like this `[ 0-9a-zA-Z](\d{1,6})?`. Don't you?

Comment: If it is supposed to match the entire string, something more like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$`.  Assuming HTML5 support ...